# How to capture screenshot of a command runs in Linux

Tags: screenshot

Is there any way to capture a screenshot of the executed command output in Linux?

Example: We have the command `ls -lrt /root/`.

Whatever the output of the above command, I want to capture it in an image.

Comment: you could redirect the output into a file

Answer (score 1):

You can make a screenshot of a terminal window ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot ). To make it free from any additional data you may run `clear` before any such command.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be using imagemagick with a command like:

```
ls -lrt /root/ |fmt | convert -size 1000x2000 xc:white -font "CourierNew" -pointsize 24 -fill black -annotate +15+30 "@-" -trim -bordercolor "#FFF" -border 10 +repage image.png
```

Basically, you need to format the text so that imagemagick can handle it correctly.
Therefor you must pipe the command via "fmt".

Only then you can convert the text output into an image with the command "convert". I have used here CourierNew, since I am used to that font :-D but if you don't like it, a "convert -list font | grep Font:" will give you all the fonts you can use.

I hope that helps answer your question!